# asp.net 3.5 ajax hosting

Tags: asp.net, ajax

i have developed and uploaded a website wich is asp.net 3.5 and I used the ajax tab control in it , I want to know if asp.net 3.5 host is different with asp.net 3.5 ajax host ? and do i need to upload that site on asp.net 3.5 ajax host if those two are different ?
please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the hosting panel gives you the option to switch among the available ASP.NET frameworks, be sure you have selected the 2.0 Framework on the ASP.NET settings of it because Ajax 3.5 works as an extension of it. That's what you have to care about.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same, there is no difference required for asp.net 3.5 if you are using ajax.